# Como adicionar um arquivo binário à pilha de maneira que grave a operação ao inserir um novo item e ao remover um item

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct paginaweb{
    int numero;
    char link[128];
}Pagina;

typedef struct pilha{
    Pagina pg[MAX];
    int topo, fundo;
}Pilha;

void inicializa(Pilha *p){
    p->topo=0;
    p->fundo=p->topo;
}

int pilhavazia(Pilha p){
    return(p.topo == p.fundo);
}

void empilhar(Pilha *p, Pagina pgn){
    if(p->fundo < MAX){
        p->pg[p->fundo] = pgn;
        p->fundo++;
        printf("\nPagina Inserida na Pilha\n");
    }else{
        printf("\nNao e possivel empilhar, pois a Pilha esta cheia\n");
    }
}

void desempilhar(Pilha *p){
    if(!pilhavazia(*p)){
        p->fundo--;
        printf("\nPagina removida da pilha\n\n");
    }else{
        printf("\nNao e possivel desempilhar, pois a pilha esta vazia\n");
    }
}

void mostrarPilha(Pilha p){
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<p.fundo;i++){
        printf("\nPAGINA [%d] -> NUMERO: %d - LINK: %s\n", i, p.pg[i].numero, p.pg[i].link);
    }
}
int main()
{
    Pilha URL;
    Pagina pgn;
    int opc=5;
    
    inicializa(&URL);
    while(opc>0){
        printf("\n---------------------MENU----------------\n");
        printf("--------------------1-EMPILHAR-------------\n");
        printf("--------------------2-DESEMPILHAR----------\n");
        printf("--------------------3-MOSTRAR--------------\n");
        printf("--------------------0-SAIR-----------------\n");
        printf("\nOPCAO DESEJADA: ");
        scanf("%d",&opc);
    
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
            printf("\nNumero: ");
            scanf("%d", &pgn.numero);
            printf("Link: ");
            scanf("%s", pgn.link);
            empilhar(&URL, pgn);
            break;
        
            case 2:
            desempilhar(&URL);
            break;
        
            case 3:
            mostrarPilha(URL);
            break;
            
            default:
            printf("\nOPCAO INVALIDA!\n");
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Boas-vindas Breno. É importante ler e compreender o [mcve], depois de compreendido pode [edit] a pergunta. Se a edição atender aos **critérios**, será avaliada por diferentes usuários na [fila de análises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro) e poderá ser reaberta. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: A conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138999/discussion-on-question-by-breno-uchoa-como-adicionar-um-arquivo-binario-a-pilha). Para dúvidas de como o site funciona, consultem: [help], [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/3635) e [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/3635)